Reality of Connection or Meromorphic Function
Let's considering a family of connections: $\nabla^{\lambda}:\mathbb{C}^{*}\rightarrow \Omega^{1}(sl(2,C))$ of trivial rank2 bundle on $\mathbb{P}^{1}-\{ 0,1,\infty \}$ with simple pole. In this case, assuming we could write $\nabla^{\lambda}=d+A_{0}(\lambda)\frac{dz}{z}+A_{1}(\lambda)\frac{dz}{z-1}$, $A_{0}(\lambda)=\begin{pmatrix} \alpha(\lambda)&& 0 \\ 0 && -\alpha(\lambda)\end{pmatrix}
$, $A_{1}(\lambda)=\begin{pmatrix} \beta(\lambda)&& \gamma(\lambda) \\ \delta(\lambda) && -\beta(\lambda)\end{pmatrix}$, where each term has the form $a_{-1}\lambda^{-1}+....$.
My question is: if we have the equation $\nabla^{\lambda}$ gauge equivalent
$\overline{\nabla^{-\bar{\lambda}^{-1}}}$, could you give me what this family of connections looks like?
If you don't feel comfortable with these notations, I simply this question to a system of equations:
1.$\alpha(\lambda)=a_{-1}\lambda^{-1}+a_{0}-\overline{a_{-1}}\lambda$.
2.$\sqrt{\beta^{2}+\delta\gamma}=b_{-1}\lambda^{-1}+b_{0}-\overline{b_{-1}}\lambda$
3.$\sqrt{(\alpha+\beta)^{2}+\delta\gamma}=c_{-1}\lambda^{-1}+(-\frac{1}{2}+iy)+ \overline{c_{-1}}       \lambda$.
Here, $a_{i},b_{i},c_{i}$ are any complex number and $y$ is real.
Could you help me explicitly give $\beta(\lambda),\delta(\lambda),\gamma(\lambda)$ which is just like $\alpha(\lambda)$ that I have already given?
If we cannot explicitly solve these things, could you give me what is $Res_{\lambda=0}\nabla^{\lambda}$ looks like?
